# Log out of Github website on a different device

Tags: github

I logged into my github account from the website from someone else's computer. I don't have access to that computer. Is there any way to log out of that computer without accessing it? Something like Google Chrome's log out of all devices feature. Note that I've actually not stored any credentials on that computer. I simply logged into the website from Safari, set Remember Password to never, and downloaded a repo as a zip.

Answer (score 17):

[The security section of your user settings page](https://github.com/settings/security) should list all of your active sessions and should provide a revoke option if you are logged in anywhere else on any device.

Answer (score 14):

To logout from Github on a device or all devices follow the steps:
`Account` => `Settings` => `Account Security`

Under `Session` section => `See session` button => `Revoke session` button

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Go to [Personal Settings -> Sessions](https://github.com/settings/sessions), there will be a list of devices. Click **See More** option against the device you want to sign out. The next page will have a red button with **Revoke Session** option, click on it and your account will be logged out from that device.

Comment: I think this fix is depricated now.

Comment: That link is now a 404 :-(

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on your profile pic(on the top right corner). Select 'Settings' from the dropdown.
2. Click 'Password and authentication' (on the left side).
3. In that section, you can see all your sessions opened on multiple devices. Click on 'see more' button to go to the screen where it gives you the option to revoke the session.

Note: These directions might need some changes later on as GitHub constantly changes its UI.